# catkin_make fails with Invalid email and Invalid package

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, catkin-ws, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to catkin_make my workspace the following is output:

```
Base path: /home/user/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/user/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/user/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/user/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/user/catkin_ws/install
Package name "${pkg_name}" does not follow naming conventions
Invalid email "${email}" for person "${author}"
Invalid email "${email}" for person "${author}"
```

When I try to launch a launchfile which had been working fine before (and nothing changed on the file or the related files):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 225, in main
    args = rlutil.resolve_launch_arguments(args)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/rlutil.py", line 92, in resolve_launch_arguments
    resolved = roslib.packages.find_resource(args[0], args[1])
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/packages.py", line 504, in find_resource
    source_path_to_packages=source_path_to_packages)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/find_in_workspaces.py", line 143, in find_in_workspaces
    source_path_to_packages[source_path] = find_packages(source_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py", line 87, in find_packages
    packages = find_packages_allowing_duplicates(basepath, exclude_paths=exclude_paths, 
exclude_subspaces=exclude_subspaces, warnings=warnings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py", line 137, in find_packages_allowing_duplicates
    xml, filename=filename, warnings=warnings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 589, in parse_package_string
    pkg.validate(warnings=warnings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 268, in validate
    raise InvalidPackage('\n'.join(errors))
InvalidPackage: Package name "${pkg_name}" does not follow naming conventions
Invalid email "${email}" for person "${author}"
Invalid email "${email}" for person "${author}"
```

What I *did* do before this occurred was following the "Create your rqt plugin package" tutorial and at some point ran cmake on the package which added a bunch of folders and files to my catkin workspace (in retrospect, I think I misunderstood the wording on the tutorial...) I tried deleting the new stuff but that just caused more errors.

I'm not sure what exactly happened and how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: The problem turned out to be exactly what the error message said, there was actually a package.xml with the placeholders ${pkg_name} etc in the catkin workspace. Removed that and everything worked again.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266898/catkin_make-fails-with-invalid-email-and-invalid-package/) by [Parr](https://answers.ros.org/users/31281/parr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry I was unclear, I had removed the new files but since that caused even more problems, put them back again. I took another look and there was actually a package.xml with the placeholders, removing that solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Parr](https://answers.ros.org/users/31281/parr/) with karma: 16 on 2017-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try removing:

- `/home/user/catkin_ws/build`
- `/home/user/catkin_ws/devel`
- `/home/user/catkin_ws/install`

then run `catkin_make` (or `catkin build`) again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Parr](https://answers.ros.org/users/31281/parr/) on 2017-07-21**:
that just creates the build and devel folders again (empty) and creates the same output:

```
Package name "${pkg_name}" does not follow naming conventions
Invalid email "${email}" for person "${author}"
Invalid email "${email}" for person "${author}"
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-21**:
Well, yes. But I had understood from your "I tried deleting the new stuff" that you removed the offending pkg(s). In that case removing those build folders should have reset things.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-21**:
I'm unsure whether this is actually a pkg that has a problem or if it's `catkin` or `rospkg` itself. What is the output of `grep '{author}' -r /home/user/catkin_ws`?